# Put a component that holds a FlatList inside a ScrollView for pull down to refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've got a component `<Component1 />` that has a `FlatList` inside of it. This component goes inside another component, `<Component2 />` which also contains other components, like so:

```
<Component2>
     <Component1 />
     <OtherComponent1 />
     <OtherComponent2 />
</Component2>
```

I'm trying to add pull down to refresh to all of the components inside `<Component2 />` by wrapping them all in a `<ScrollView />` for RefreshControl. However, I am warned by React Native that this is very bad practice. What is the best way to go about this? I appreciate your help!

Comment: add <OtherComponent1 /> and <OtherComponent2 /> as list-footer component.

Comment: @TusharPandey What if `<OtherComponent1 />` and `<OtherComponent2 />` can't be placed into the `<Component1 />` file as a list-header/list-footer component? Is there a way to keep the decoupling?

Comment: how they are coupled inside list footer component ?